# global variable in django (singleton)

Tags: python, django

I have django app.
App - client for site with authorization
App contains some methods which run periodically, but all methods created auth objects, for example: method runs 10 times, with 10 re-autorization.
I tried session to store that object but get error:

```
def get_api_instance(request):
    if 'api' not in request.session: 
        api = auth()
        request.session['api'] = api
    return request.session['api']


<****api.api.Api object at 0x7fe30d155550> is not JSON serializable
```

Can you recommend something?

UPD:
in simple python script i can create global variable:

```
api_var = None

def get_api():
   if not api_var:
      api_var = auth()
   return api_var

def periodic():
   api = get_api_var()
   ....
```

Comment: are you requesting data with  json header?

Comment: jithin, no. I create api(which is wrapper) object and run methods in it.

Comment: The session has nothing to do with global objects and is not an appropriate place to do this. Can you explain a bit more about the object? Is it per-user?

Comment: @daniel-roseman, yes, one user has only one api_auth_instance

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function to the User object to get the Auth class instance, you can also use propery caching to only create it once:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_get_auth(self):
    # Initialze the Auth class here

    return Auth()


User.add_to_class("get_auth", property(user_get_auth))
```

in the views.py or templates you can get the Auth class by:

```
request.user.get_auth.some_method()
```